# Can "straightforward" be replaced by "straight" in this case?

Tags: word-choice

> Their ‘complexity’ is relatively straightforward. (Woolhouse The
>   empiricists, p. 88)

I check a dictionary, it says that “straight” can also mean “straightforward”. Do you think that here I can replace “straightforward” with “straight”?

Comment: The word _straight_ has several meanings, so it might be harder to figure out what the person is getting at after you switched the words around. It wouldn't introduce a grammatical error, but I'd strongly advise against the edit.

Comment: No. Straightforward is a manner of addressing things. In that capacity, *straight* is slang: *Lemme give it to you **straight** .* Not used.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that *straightforward* is an adjective, and that *straight* used in the context the dictionary refers to (likely the informal/slang "Give the news to me straight") is an adverb, so actually it would be replacing the word *straightforwardly*.

In the example you give, I think it is clear that *straightforward* is being used as an adjective.

Answer (score 2):

No. In this case, **straight** means without curving or bending. Like an arrow. **Straightforward** in this example means simple, trivial, or non-complex.